# How do I use NavigationPage correctly with a rootpage as MainPage?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How should I use the rootpage correctly so I can navigate/pushasync to other pages with the correct navigatiobar.

Right now It looks like this:

```
MainPage = new RootPage ();
```

And my rootpage:

```
public RootPage ()
    {

        var theMenu = new MenuPage (this);
        theMenu.Title = "::";

        Master = theMenu;

        NavigationPage page = new NavigationPage(new StartPage ());
        Detail = page;
    }
```

If i have it like this, i get an error when I try to navigate to a new page:

```
async void contactClick (object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync (new ContactPage());
    }
```

Error: "PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage."

If i instead do :

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage (new RootPage ());
```

I get two navigationbars. I solved it by using...:

```
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, false);
```

...on my RootPage but that gives it a weird animation when I navigate to new pages and also it crashes on android. Any ideas how you would solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you have MasterDetailPage and you want to perform navigation on Detail page.

If so, you should push/pop pages via Detail.Navigation.Push/Popasync(..) (your Detail page is already NavigationPage).

---

```
async void contactClick (object s, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync (new ContactPage());
    }
```

If this method is in MenuPage or RootPage then you got

> Error: "PushAsync is not supported globally on iOS, please use a NavigationPage."

because this pages are not NavigationPages.

**EDIT**: if you want to hide menu after navigation, set RootPage.IsPresented property to false.

Comment: Ok. Code runs, and the page changes, but the problem is that the menupage (that works as the masterdetailpage Master) remains and the page on the right changes. so I have to manually click away the menupage to go to the page and then press back

Comment: Hard to explain, but when I use detail.navigation.pushasync, the page on the right changes but the masterpage still remains on the leftside of the app. it doesnt push to the entire next page

Comment: Can you explain what you want: change only Detail page or replace whole MasterDetail page with new page?

Comment: i want to go to an entire new contentpage and when i press back i get back to the masterdetailpage with the same detail/master as before.

Comment: oh i did not see your edit. now it works fine. only issue is that when u go back, i would like the menupage to be presented again.

Comment: @medvedo I want to understand why you need "entire new contentpage".
For example, if you choose some item in menu, it is right to show new page in Detail

Comment: yeah. i will probably change my code a bit. thanks alot for the help.

Comment: @Flame239 Thanks for the hint. I was missing out on the NavigationPage too, and having the Master Details I got the issue too. Navigation is the most challenging part of forms :)

Answer (score 0):

Take peek at these examples:

- https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/PhonewordMultiscreen/
- https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/Navigation/TabbedPageWithNavigationPage/

Comment: Also, take a peek here - https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms-multiscreen/quickstart/

Comment: It is expect on SO that an answer will not consist solely of links. Evn when links provide most of the needed information, the answer needs to identify the problem and have a summary of the solution or of what the links are about.